# How can I rename files to a unique name that is fool proof in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

My app needs to copy/move thousands of files throughout the day to a directory.  I need to ensure that when I copy over these files I rename them to something that is unique for that directory.

I have no requirements for the names other than they need to obviously be unique.

What is the proper way to handle this?  Should I use some kind of GUID, some incrementing number or some other method?

How would I do this in C#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Path.GetRandomFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx)

However I don't think the generated filenames are guaranteed to be unique (they are generated using [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx)), so a GUID might be a better idea

Comment: So just wrap this is a File.Exists() loop to ensure that file doesn't exist and if not, create it?

Comment: The problem with File.Exists() is it leads to race conditions. Just put the rename process in a try-catch block, and if an exception is thrown then just do it again. You'll have to research which type it is when a file already exists, as I can't remember off the top of my head.

Answer (score 6):

I tend to use

```
System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg"
```

when the only requirement is that they are absolutely required to be guaranteed to be unique.

This is, of course, already one of your ideas, so +1 to you for thinking of it first.

Answer (score 3):

Use a GUID. Details are coming.

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5708732.html

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use GUID's. They are unique, and a filename can get generated with

```
String filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".MyExtension";
```

br, Marcel

Comment: Note that GUID are not guaranteed to be unique... there is just a very low probability of generating the same GUID twice

Comment: Thomas, you are right. The probability is however so small, that it probably takes longer to wait for the end of the world than for a non-unique Guid coming out the Guid class. :-)

Comment: In any case, I would check if the file exist, and put that in a loop with x repetition. I know that the probability are small, but it's there and it should be handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the new file name to resemble the old one you could use this solution:

```
string oldFileName = @"c:\old\oldfile.txt";
string newFileName = oldFileName.Substring(0, oldFileName.LastIndexOf('.')) + "-";
string oldFileNameExtension = oldFileName.Substring( oldFileName.LastIndexOf('.')+1 );
File.Move(oldFileName, newFileName + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + oldFileNameExtension);
```

DateTime.Ticks is an integer of type Long which contains the current date converted to nanoseconds.  Beware: most CPU's can perform many operations before the Ticks counter is advanced.

If you are doing many files at once you will have to add a `while(File.Exists())` loop with a `Thread.Sleep(10);` in it.  Or if you don't want to slow it down with Thread.Sleep you could add a counter to the loop and append that to the end of newFileName.